# UML attribute to association class or simple class?

Tags: class, uml, associations, class-diagram

I'm having a difficulty figuring out where to put the Level attribute. I want the employee to have a variety of skills which have different levels. For that purpose I made a many to many relationship which is implemented as an EmployeeSkill association class.

An example of said class is as follows: An employee named Jack might have a skill of Java which is level beginner, while he could also have a skill of C# which is advanced level. Should the level be saved in the EmployeeSkill association class or in the Skill class? I suspect it should be on the association class.

[image: The image of the UML diagram in drawio]

Comment: There is no associaton class in your UML diagram.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still learning UML, is EmployeeSkill not considered an association class which connects the M:M relationship of employee and skill classes?

Comment: It could be modelled as an associationclass, but you didn't do that. You modelled a regular class with two associations. (Also all of your classes are apparently abstract, indicated by the italic style of the name)

Comment: Ok so that's two things I need to fix which I'll upload later. Can you also tell me where you put the Level attribute?

Comment: depends, you can either create an instance of `Skill` for every combination of Skill/Level, or (which makes more sense) store the level in the `EmployeeSkill` class.

Comment: I've updated the drawio image, any comments are welcome.

Comment: Your nesting connector is wrong. This is only allowed for packages. Also all the `id` attributes seem superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

### A property of the association class?

Your narrative with the `Employee` instance `"Jack"` being associated with `Skill` instance `"Java"` with a `level` of `"beginner"` shows that the skill is independent of the level, and the level is related to the combination of a given employee and a given skill.

To model accurately the semantic of this narrative, `level` should indeed be the property of the association class `EmployeeSkill`.

### Could it be a property of the skills?

It would not be wrong to move `level` as a property of `Skill`. But the model would have a different semantic, since every `Employee` associated with a `Skill` would share the same level. This means that `"Jack"` being associated to a skill like `"Java"` but rather a skill like `Elementary Java`.

This alternative model makes it also less convenient to desperately search for all employees knowing  about  `Neural network` regardless of the level. And it would not be obvious for the system to see that `elementary neural network` is related to `advanced neural network expertise` and that  `Advanced java` has little to do with `Advanced javascript`.

To have the same power of expression, the skills that are related but correspond to a different level would require an explicit association, which would make the model more cumbersome to use and fragile.

### Remarks that are unrelated to your question

- You seem to repeat the `JobCategory`'s and the `Country`'s attribute within `Employee`. This is confusing, as the associations already associate the class with another set of each of these attributes. Did you mean the redundant attributes to implement the associations and show the db table layout than the class? If so, you should disambiguate using some [custom stereotypes](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/umlDataModelingProfile.html). But I'd rather recommend to remove the redundant items and make a comment at the bottom of the diagram to explain that you implement associations.
- I wonder if the multiplicities of the association between `Skill` and `SkillCategory` are not inverted (i.e. one category can have several skills and each skill is associated with only one category) ?  Or that you meant a many-to-many association if skills can belong to several categories.
- In the association class you use the prefix FK to highlight the foreign keys.  Use `<<FK>>` to make it a custom stereotype (see may first remark about using stereotypes).
- As [qwerty_so](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3379653/qwerty-so) pointed out in the comments, you use a nesting connector for the associations with enumerations.  This is syntactically acceptable but does not mean what you think.  This is meant to deal with namespaces.  Just remove that circle-plus symbol to make it a normal association and it will mean what you think.

Comment: You should at least note that the nesting connector is wrong. See pp. 246 and 716 of UML. It's only allowed for packages (showing namespaces),

Comment: @qwerty_so Interesting remark. I have to admit that I just looked at the two associated classes and their association class.  Now that you tell it, there is indeed a couple of nested classifiers.  While I'm not so keen of that notation,  I understand from UML 7.4.4.1 that it's valid for classes as well:  "Conforming tools may optionally allow the “circle-plus” notation defined in sub clause 12.2.4 to show Package membership **to also be used to show membership in other kinds of Namespaces** (***for example, to show nestedClassifiers*** and ownedBehaviors of Classes)."

Comment: Well, I don't think that nesting is appropriate in that case. It's just that those are enumerations. This should be a dependency and the attributes are typed with these enumerations. People tend to use fancy connectors without knowing theis meaning. Basically I would avoid that connector since even the UML editors chooese a wording that makes them appear "strange".

Comment: @qwerty_so I agree.  I made a model comprehensive review of the diagram and have added your point and others that may be worth to be mentioned, but that are not related to the question.